# Visual Hull C++ and marching cube

Tags: c++, 3d-modelling, marching-cubes

I am quite new in 3D modelling field and I need to create a visual hull and marching cube in c++. So, I have a set of binary masks, camera matrix and I would like to create a  STL file. I don't really understand how this algorithms are working and maybe someone can explain it in a easy way. Moreover can you recommend me some papers for reading and c++ libraries that might help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Googling for it is not enough?

Comment: There are many very good papers on Marching Cubes, including the original. Look at http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/, google "isosurface recreation," etc. This is very well-traveled  (and well-documented) territory.

Comment: @3Dave Where should be a good place to post a question regarding a paper https://areeweb.polito.it/ricerca/cgvg/Articles/pami94.pdf ?

Comment: @JuneWang Computer vision questions are applicable to signals processing, coding (StackOverflow), machine learning and a bunch of other areas. Which forum would be appropriate depends on what your specific question is. This is a bit outside of my purview.

Comment: @3Dave My question is specifically about the 3D geometry part, not sure ml/signal processing is a fit. Thank you tho.